# how to increment the value of a char in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I increment a string "A" to get "B" in Javascript?

```
function incrementChar(c)
{


}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if you call `incrementChar('Z')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a method that can be used to increment letters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504042/what-is-a-method-that-can-be-used-to-increment-letters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try

```
var yourChar = 'A'
var newChar = String.fromCharCode(yourChar.charCodeAt(0) + 1) // 'B'
```

So, in a function:

```
function incrementChar(c) {
    return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1)
}
```

Note that this goes in [ASCII order](http://www.asciitable.com/), for example `'Z' -> '['`. If you want Z to go back to A, try something slightly more complicated:

```
var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')
function incrementChar(c) {
    var index = alphabet.indexOf(c)
    if (index == -1) return -1 // or whatever error value you want
    return alphabet[index + 1 % alphabet.length]
}
```

Comment: `index + i`, I guess you meant `index + 1`?

Comment: @plalx Whoops, yep. That was a typo. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
var incrementString = function(string, count){
    var newString = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        newString[i] = String.fromCharCode(string[i].charCodeAt() + count);
    }
    newString = newString.join('');
    console.log(newString);

    return newString;
}
```

this function also can help you if you have a loop to go through