# simple javascript appendChild doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm new to web programming. I have tried to draw a table row with JavaScript but it's not working and I don't' know why.

here's the code

```
<div id="gameDiv"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    public function drawGame(){ 
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.setAttribute('style','float:left');
        var startRow = table.insertRow(0);
        var c = 'A'
        for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
            var text = document.createTextNode(c++);
            var cell = startRow.insertCell(j);
            cell.appendChild(text);
        }
        document.getElementById("gameDiv").appendChild(table);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        drawGame();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't currently use access modifiers, like `public`, as you might find in other languages; there's a closing `)` missing for `.ready()` between the `};`; and string values like `'A'` don't support incrementing, as `c++` is attempting.

Comment: Always open your browser console while working with JS.

Comment: The variable c is also a string, and you cannot increment it with ++.

Comment: thank you guys, now I have a new problem. how can I show row with alphabets in an incremented way. something like A B C D F... and do it dynamically with a loop

Comment: @user3503716 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504042 (see also my answer ;) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the fact you use `public`. Javascript doesn't have `public` or `private`, so putting that in front of your function declaration will cause errors. If you open up your console, you'll see an error like:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

So to fix this, simply remove the `private` modifier from your code.

Also, you seem to be missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your code. Instead, you should use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    drawGame();
});
```

but that code could also be written much shorter:

```
$(drawGame);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're getting an error because I think you might be getting your languages mixed up, there's no need to declare a function as public in javascript, it will give you an error.

The drawGame function can just be:

```
    function drawGame(){ 
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.setAttribute('style','float:left');
        var startRow = table.insertRow(0);
        var c = 'A'
        for(j=0; j<8; j++){
            var text = document.createTextNode(c++);
            var cell = startRow.insertCell(j);

            cell.appendChild(text);

        }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is kind of working variant http://jsbin.com/hisewamu/4/edit, "$" notion is part from jquery that you should include

Answer (score 0):

This should get rid of that NaN (Not a Number) nonsense.

```
<script>
        function drawGame(){ 
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.setAttribute('style','float:left');
        var startRow = table.insertRow(0);
        var c = 'A'.charCodeAt()
        for(j=0; j<8; j++){
            var text = document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(c++));
            var cell = startRow.insertCell(j);

            cell.appendChild(text);

        }
    document.getElementById("gameDiv").appendChild(table);

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
    drawGame();

    });
</script>
```