# Change keys of array object after inserting in the middle/first of array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I am working on an Excel-like application, but I am having problems with a multi-dimensional array.

I have array of columns that looks like this:

```
var columns = [
  {A: {binding: "A",header: "A"},
  {B: {binding: "B",header: "B"},
  {C: {binding: "C",header: "C"}
];
```

And then I have an array representing the value of every cell that looks like this:

```
var data = [
   {A:"row 0 col A", B: "row 0 col B", C:"row 0 col C"},
   {A:"row 1 col A", B: "row 1 col B", C:"row 1 col C"},
   {A:"row 2 col A", B: "row 2 col B", C:"row 2 col C"}
];
```

The `binding` property of the objects in the `columns` array will be used to get the column's value for each row.

However, I am encountering an issue when inserting a new column in the middle of some alphabetical keys.
Let's say I need a new column between column `A` and column `B`. The result looks like this:

```
var columns = [
  {A: {binding: "A",header: "A"},
  {B: {binding: "B",header: "B"},
  {C: {binding: "C",header: "C"},
  {D: {binding: "D",header: "D"}
];
```

It's just pushing the new column onto `columns`.

I think I have to insert a new cell/item between all alphabetical keys for every row, and rename all the keys (in this case, rename keys `B` to `C`, `C` to `D`, etc).

I would like the result to look like this:

```
var data = [
   {A:"row 0 col A", B:"new col inserted here", C:"row 0 col B", D:"row 0 col C"},
   {A:"row 1 col A", B:"new col inserted here", C:"row 1 col B", D:"row 1 col C"},
   {A:"row 2 col A", B:"new col inserted here", C:"row 2 col B", D:"row 2 col C"}
];
```

I'm concerned about performance issues if I were to rename all these keys, especially if I have 120 columns (A-DZ) and 100 rows.

I have two questions:

- What is the most efficient way to do this?
- Will I have performance issues when renaming these keys if I have lots of rows and columns?

Comment: When you insert, how do you choose the new rightmost column name?  Here it's 'D', but how do you determine it in the arbitrary case?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the performance of renaming ~12K keys, unless I tested and saw it was a problem.  I would expect it to be quick.

Comment: @ScottSauyet i use this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504042/what-is-a-method-that-can-be-used-to-increment-letters/34483399, but i need to modify it a little so i can set the starting char. example: i want the function to start incremental from char 'C'

Comment: I know you want the new column to be visible in between A and B in the UI but Why do you need it between A and B ? Are you using sequential index to access is it? like index 0 mean A and index 1 means B and so on

Comment: I think @Andam has it right here.  Objects are inherently unordered containers.  If you maintain an external array of property names representing the columns, then an insertion is just updating that array (and possibly adding default values for the new property name on each row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I think the comment to the question from Andam is correct.  There are certainly better ways of making a spreadsheet-like display out of an array of objects.  My thought would simply to maintain an array of header objects containing (at a minimum) a column title and the name of the property to show in the column.  Then inserting a column would simply involve updating that array (and perhaps defaulting that property value for your rows.)

But you still want to proceed in the manner suggested by your question, here's a possible implementation:

```js
// Utility function
const alphaNum = (cs) => (n) => 
  n < cs.length
    ? cs [n % cs.length]
    : alphaNum (cs) (Math.floor(n / cs.length) - 1) + cs [n % cs.length]

// Helper function
const toColumnName = alphaNum ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' .split (''))

// Main function
const insertColumn = (index, data, makeVal) => 
  data .map ((item, i, arr, vals = Object .values (item)) => Object.fromEntries ([
    ...vals .slice (0, index),
    makeVal (item, i, index),
    ...vals .slice (index)
  ] .map ((item, i) => [toColumnName(i), item])))

// Dummy cell creation function
const createCell = (row, rowNbr, colNbr) => 
  `new col inserted at row ${rowNbr} col ${colNbr}`

// Sample data
const data = [{A: 'row 0 col A', B: 'row 0 col B', C: 'row 0 col C'}, {A: 'row 1 col A', B: 'row 1 col B', C: 'row 1 col C'}, {A: 'row 2 col A', B: 'row 2 col B', C: 'row 2 col C'}]

// Demo
console .log (insertColumn (1, data, createCell))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

- **`toColumnName`** simply converts a (zero-based) index into a spreadsheet-like column identifier (`'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, ... `'Z'`, `'AA'`, `'AB'`, ... `'AZ'`, `'BA'`, `'BB'`, ... `'BZ'`, ... `'ZZ'`, `'AAA'`, ...)
- It uses **`alphaNum`**, which does the heavy-lifting, based on an array of characters to represent the pseudo-digits used.
- **`insertColumn`** is the main function.  It takes the (zero-based) index of the inserted column, the data, and a function used to create your cell value.  It changes each row by extracting the values, inserting the new one created by your function, and then mapping back to the column names from the new indices, then rebuilding the object with `Object .fromEntries`.

Here we pass it a dummy column-creation function, which, we can note, is passed the row object, the row index and the new column index.

I have no idea how it will perform on your realistic data, but the numbers you described wouldn't worry me overmuch.  There are some minor optimizations you could do here.  For instance, we don't need to recalculate the column names for each row and could cache them instead.  But I would only bother with them if the performance doesn't meet your expectations.

And, once again, I think there are better ways to solve the likely underlying problem.

Comment: i agree with you, there's a lot of better way to solve this problem, like @eduardo suggest. but i cant change the data structure of my 'ready to publish' app like that.

Comment: Understood.  That's why I gave an answer that I think might help.  But if you get time to refactor this, it might be a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use literal names for rows or columns.

To increase performance, link one data object directly to column and/or row (make some attributes like _row and _col in cell array) and put _cells in rows and cols.

Example:

```js
var data = {};

data.rows = [
{idx: 'A', _cells: []},
{idx: 'B', _cells: []},
{idx: 'C', _cells: []}
]

data.cols = [
{idx: 'A', _cells: []},
{idx: 'B', _cells: []},
{idx: 'C', _cells: []}
]

data.cells = [];

function addCell( rowIdx, colIdx, value) {
  var row = data.rows[rowIdx];
  var col = data.cols[rowIdx];
  var cell = {value: value, _row: row, _col: col};
  data.cells.push(cell);
  row._cells.push(cell);
  col._cells.push(cell);
}

for(var r=0; r<3; r++)
  for (var c=0;c<3; c++)
    addCell(r,c,'row ' + r + ' col ' + String.fromCharCode(65 + c));

console.log(data);
```

so... you can insert/delete/sort/rename rows without difficulty.

You can insert/delete/sort/rename all cells from a column without difficulty.

If order is important, you can "map" cells sorted by row/col

Comment: An interesting approach, but I would be worried about the various circular references.  Is there a good reason that cells need references back to their rows and columns?

Comment: well, if you need create a new "full" row or col, it's not need! But if you wanna create a cell "before",  the row shift will be a lot easer inside "cols"